# A conjecture on eigenvalues of special matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is an observation from some simple matrices, but I am not sure if the conjecture below is true for the general case.

> Suppose all the off-diagonal entries of a real square matrix $A$ are nonpositive, then $A$ doesn't have pure imaginary eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Its off-diagonal entries (in fact, all its entries) are nonpositive, but it has $i$ as an eigenvalue.